# Is aws-go-sdk-v2 integrated with local MinIO server?

Tags: go, aws-sdk, minio, aws-sdk-go

How can I hook up my local minIO storage with `aws-sdk-go-v2`? I can find clear documentation of how to do that in the previous version of go SDK but not with V2. I read through the version 2 source code and it seems `aws-sdk-go-v2` removed the option to disable SSL and specify a local S3 endpoint(the service URL has to be in amazon style).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this easily enough with:

```
const defaultRegion = "us-east-1"
staticResolver := aws.EndpointResolverFunc(func(service, region string) (aws.Endpoint, error) {
    return aws.Endpoint{
        PartitionID:       "aws",
        URL:               "http://localhost:9123", // or where ever you ran minio
        SigningRegion:     defaultRegion,
        HostnameImmutable: true,
    }, nil
})

cfg = aws.Config{
    Region:           defaultRegion,
    Credentials:      credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider("minioadmin", "minioadmin", ""),
    EndpointResolver: staticResolver,
}

s3Client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)
```

Comment: Thank you danmux. Your solution worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As of today aws.EndpointResolverFunc is deprecated this is what worked for me:

```
const defaultRegion = "us-east-1"
hostAddress := "http://localhost:9000"

resolver := aws.EndpointResolverWithOptionsFunc(func(service, region string, options ...any) (aws.Endpoint, error) {
    return aws.Endpoint{
        PartitionID:       "aws",
        URL:               hostAddress,
        SigningRegion:     defaultRegion,
        HostnameImmutable: true,
    }, nil
})

cfg, err = config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.Background(),
    config.WithRegion(defaultRegion),
    config.WithEndpointResolverWithOptions(resolver),
    config.WithCredentialsProvider(credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider("minioadmin", "minioadmin", "")),
)
s3Client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)
```

Answer (score 1):

A derived version for aws-sdk-go-v2

```
const defaultRegion = "us-east-1"
hostAddress := "http://localhost:9000"

resolver := aws.EndpointResolverWithOptionsFunc(func(service, region string, options ...any) (aws.Endpoint, error) {
    return aws.Endpoint{
        PartitionID:       "aws",
        SigningRegion:     defaultRegion,
        URL:               hostAddress,
        HostnameImmutable: true,
    }, nil
})

cfg := aws.Config{
    Region:      defaultRegion,
    EndpointResolverWithOptions: resolver
    Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider("minioadmin", "minioadmin", ""),
}

return s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)
```

Answer (score 1):

For aws-sdk-go-v2 with `EndpointResolverV2`

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/smithy-go/endpoints"

    "io"
    "net/url"
)

type Resolver struct {
    URL *url.URL
}

func (r *Resolver) ResolveEndpoint(_ context.Context, params s3.EndpointParameters) (transport.Endpoint, error) {
    u := *r.URL
    u.Path += "/" + *params.Bucket
    return transport.Endpoint{URI: u}, nil
}

func main() {

    endpointURL, _ := url.Parse("http://localhost:9000") // or where ever you ran minio

    client := s3.New(s3.Options{
        EndpointResolverV2: &Resolver{URL: endpointURL},
        Credentials: aws.CredentialsProviderFunc(func(ctx context.Context) (aws.Credentials, error) {
            return aws.Credentials{
                AccessKeyID:     "minioadmin",
                SecretAccessKey: "minioadmin",
            }, nil
        }),
    })

    ...
}
```